# How to stop openpyxl - python from clearing my excel file every time I re-run the program?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I wrote a simple program for testing with openpyxl where I simply open the .xlsx file, input data into a certain cell, then close the program and run it again, inputting data in a different cell, but when I open the .xlsx after running the program for the second.

My assumption is that openpyxl clears the entire .xlsx file everytime you open it again, is there a way to avoid this?

Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = 'teste.xlsx'

ws = wb.active
ws.title = "2017"

Row = int(input('row: '))
Column = int(input('column: '))
data = input('data: ')

ws.cell(row = Row, column = Column).value = data

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Here is the .xlsx file after running the program for the first time
[image]

Here is the .xlsx file after running the program for the second time
[image]

Comment: This creates a new file called "teste.xlsx" every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not read the excel file at all:

Use this to read the existing workbook:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook
import os

dest_filename = 'teste.xlsx'

if os.path.isfile(dest_filename):
    wb = load_workbook(filename = dest_filename)
else:
    wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active
ws.title = "2017"

Row = int(input('row: '))
Column = int(input('column: '))
data = input('data: ')

ws.cell(row = Row, column = Column).value = data

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: did you add load_workbook to the import line  `from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook`?

Comment: Sorry for editing my first comment, but no I hadn't.

Comment: @Sens no worries, glad I can help!